# how to add bearer key in header using openapiyaml file

Tags: http-headers, swagger, authorization, openapi

I am trying to create API endpoints using open API 3.0. I was able to create the required endpoints but stuck with the Authorisation part.

I need the Authorization to be added in the headers of my API, I referred to this "https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/bearer-authentication/" document.

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: Endpoints 
  version: 1.0.0
servers:
 - url: localhost:8080
security:
 - bearerAuth: []
paths:
   /path to my endpoint:
 post:
  tags:
  - Notification
  security: 
    - bearerAuth: []
 requestBody:
    content:
      application/json:
        schema:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/definedschema'
components:
  securitySchemes:
    bearerAuth: 
      type: http
      scheme: bearer
      bearerFormat: JWT     
  schemas:{}
```

The above code is a sample of my API endpoint, and the way I implemented authorization.
please suggest a way to implement authorization in the headers of the API endpoint.

Comment: The indentation is off: 1) `/path ...` must be indented between `paths:` and `post:`; 2) `requestBody` must be inside `post:`, on the same level as `tags:` and `security:`. Use https://editor.swagger.io to verify the indentation. Other than that, your API definition is correct, i.e. your use of `components.securitySchemes` and `security` is the correct way to define Bearer authentication. If this definition doesn't work for you after fixing the indents, please explain the exact problem you're having (e.g. what result you expect and what result you actually get).

Comment: Thanks for the help, it's because of indentation and some changes in the backend of my logic. It's working now.